# SQL Server 2005 : change collation for the existing database and LINQ2SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 database. It was created with default collation which is not case-sensitive (my fault!). That's different from all other databases which I work with, where collations are by default case sensitive. I mostly consider comparing strings than sorting. I use Linq-to-SQL where there is no way to specify collation for `WHERE` clause.

It seems that changing collation of existing database / server (and all tables' fields!) is error-prone and there is no tools for this.

Maybe I'm missing something and there is a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[ SAPWD= StrongPassword ] 
/SQLCOLLATION=CollationName
```

Run this comman through SQL command promt and then rebuild the master database.

For specific DB

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname
COLLATE French_CI_AS ;
GO
```

Comment: What if I have any other databases on this server instance?

Comment: you can see the command there abbove it will clearly asks the instance name.So it will change for that particular instance

Comment: It will change the collation across the server.

Comment: I mean what if other databases of this instance should be left intact?

Comment: I ahve give you both the commands specific to DB and specific to server

Comment: Thanks, will the command for the DB change all collations for columns too?